# How to emulate a printer in C#

Tags: virtual-printer

I'm creating a C# application which would work with a printer. I don't have a printer and I need to debug an application.

Is there any idea about how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) which provides a virtual printer that outputs PDF and some other formats. It should support most functionality of a physical USB/network printer so that you can effectively debug your application.

Though I doubt this question has any thing to do with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should install a virtual printer, such as PDFCreator.

See http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

Answer (score 1):

Use [DoPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/), After you install this free application, you can find on your "Devices And Printers" as one as your printer, and it will print your document into PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the "use a PDF printer driver" answers, Windows Vista/7/8 all ship with a "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". XPS is basically an XML-based PDF-style format and should be sufficient for testing your application.